# Running tests with selenium webdriver > PhantomJSDriver on Teamcity windows client

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, teamcity

I am trying to achieve running UI test with teamcity. I could deploy my asp.net site with msbuild and than in the next step try to run nunit tests which use selenium webdriver and PhantomJSDriver. If I run tests with nunit GUI on build agent it works. But When it runs with build it fails with the following error.

// test

```
var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
            driverService.Port = 4545;
            driverService.WebSecurity = false;

            using (var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService))
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(_rootUrl + "login.aspx");
                driver.Close();
                driver.Quit();
            }
```

// exception

```
  Test(s) failed. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:4545
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
       at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS.PhantomJSDriver..ctor(PhantomJSDriverService service, PhantomJSOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS.PhantomJSDriver..ctor(PhantomJSDriverService service, PhantomJSOptions options)
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that Selenium can't connect to the server:

`No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:4545`

Are you sure the `_rootUrl` should be pointing to *localhost*?